# Newly created directories and files are assigned to docker group

Tags: permissions, docker, groups, username

so I was recently doing some post-installation steps for Docker and I think it was after I added my user to the docker group by

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

newly created files and directories began to be assigned to the docker group by default. How do I change that behavior so that they are assigned to the group that has same name as my Linux username?

---

[Post-installation steps for Linux | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I found the answer. This behavior began after using the following command

```
newgrp docker
```

So it seems what has to be done to use that command with one's username.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, adding you to the `docker` group lets you write to the `/var/run/docker.sock` socket through which you can control the docker daemon (because the `docker` group as read & write rights on that socket), and this is what is needed to use docker. But this `docker` group is a "supplementary" group for your userid and should remain so.

`newgrp <some_group>` makes `some_group` become your new default group for the session (the group for all the files you create), and there is no reason to use it with the `docker` group, this isn't what lets you use docker.